# Session timeout when switching Network

Tags: java, session, tomcat, mobile

We have a Java application that runs on Tomcat 6.  In most cases we leave the session inactive timeout to the default value of 30 minutes.  In some cases we extend inactive timeout to two hours based on what user ask for at login.

Say I sign into the application from the laptop and wired (connected to LAN) and stay the same the inactive session timeout works perfectly the way it is supposed to.  But if I go wireless by taking off from the LAN cable and connect to the wireless hotspot my session becomes invalid and I would have to re-login.  So switching the IP address seems to invalidate the session.

Is this a normal behavior?  Is there a way I could preserve the session when switching from one network to another?

I am not that of an expert in Tomcat so any direction will be helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you configure static IP address of your machine so that each time constant IP will go irrespective of network type?

Comment: At work I could do that.  How would setting a static work with my mobile provider.  Would I be able to use wifi hotspots if I have a static IP configuration?

Comment: Print out the session id and check if it changes, once you switch the network interface. I don't think it has something to do with the configured session timeout.

Comment: Some direction available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902533/http-session-persistence-on-tcp-disconnect

Comment: I do not know if it is general in tomcat, but invalidating session if IP changes seems **sane** as a counter-mesure against stealth of session : the cookies are normally transmitted as plain test on the wire ...

Comment: @Stefan - Yes session id changes when switching network

Comment: @vanOekel - Thank you for the link.  I will dig through the page.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I don't have a solution yet but I think I narrowed down the problem.  We front application servers with a Cisco content switch with a sticky session.  After hopping from one network to another content switch throws away the sticky session and route that request to one of the Tomcat servers.  Looks like the solution here is to implement Tomcat Clustering to distribute sessions.